# How I will get this operation of VM(Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stop/action) in Activitiy Logs

Tags: azure

Every time when I stopped My VM through OS and Azure portal I only get status like deallocate in Activity Logs

To get logs for a VM like

'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stop/action'

on Activity logs what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

We have tested this in our local environment, below statements are based on our analysis.

Generally, the value **Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/stop/action** is getting stored in the Operation column in the activity logs.

We don't have any chance to customize the activity logs widget or project the operation as a column in the portal but you can apply an operation filter and pull the resource logs related to the operation like  "start or stop or deallocate etc.,

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can publish those activity logs to the log analytics & by writing the kql queries you can pull the VM start or stop operation logs as shown below.

[image]